# $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers, compute $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers and
> $$a<b<7<c<d<30.$$Then, compute $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-1$ for $a,b,c,d$ that satisfy $$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac17+\frac1c+\frac1d=1.$$

I've found that $\frac1a>\frac3{14},$ so $a$ can be $2,3,4$.
I knew that $\frac1a>\frac3{14}$ because $\frac1a$ is greater than $\frac1b,\frac1c,\frac1d$ so, $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+\frac1d=\frac67,$ $\frac1a$ has to be greater than $\dfrac{\frac67}4.$

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)+[format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: OP, please take the time to look at Raskolnikov's edit, so that you can learn how to format your posts in the future. They really do help get better responses from the community. Thanks!

Comment: How did you conclude $1/a \leq 3/14$? And if that is true, how can $a$ be either $2$ or $3$ or $4$? Do you mean to say it *can't* be those?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it was my mistake. (1/a)>3/14 so a can be 2,3,4

Comment: > ... satisfy $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+\frac1d$? 

Are you missing an equality or inequality?

Comment: Hi! It would still help if you stated where this problem came from.

Comment: sorry, i dont know where this is from. thanks for your interest.

Comment: With a little more care, you can prove that $a=2:$ use that $b\ge a+1,c\ge8,d\ge9.$

Answer (score 1):

Removing $\frac{1}{7}$ from both sides of the constaint equation gives us:
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d} = \frac{6}{7}$$
Suppose we took the largest values of the reciprocals of $a,b,c,d,$ given $a \geq 3$. That is $a = 3$, $b = 4$, $c=8$ and $d = 9$. Then:
$$\frac{6}{7} - \left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right) = \frac{19}{504} > 0,$$
therefore $a = 2$, and our equation simplifies to:
$$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d} = \frac{5}{14}.$$
Since $b > a$, suppose $b=3$, then
$$\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d} = \frac{1}{42}.$$
This is impossible as $\frac{1}{29} >\frac{1}{42}$, therefore $b \geq 4$. If $b = 4$, then
$$\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d} = \frac{3}{28},$$
from which it becomes pretty clear that we can choose $c=14$ and $d=28$ to satisfy the equation.

$$a^2 + b^2 +c^2 +d^2 - 1 = 2^2 + 4^2 + 14^2 + 28^2 - 1 = \boxed{999}$$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions.  If you go with
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{43}+\frac{1}{1806}=1$$
for example then
$$2^2+3^2+43^2+1806^2-1=3263498$$
clearly $2\le a\le5$ and $3\le b\le 6$.  There are $10$ choices for $\quad (a,b):\quad (2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,5),(4,6),(5,6)$

Whichever you choose, each solution corresponds with the solution of the following diophantine equation:

$$\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}=1-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}=\frac p q$$
just use algebra to solve into factors:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac 1 c+\frac 1 d&=\frac p q\\
c+d&=\frac p q \cdot cd\\
\frac p q \cdot cd-(c+d)&=0\\
cd-\frac q p(c+d)&=0\\
cd-\frac q p(c+d)+\left(\frac q p\right)^2&=\left(\frac q p\right)^2\\
\left(c-\frac q p\right)\left(d-\frac q p\right)&=\left(\frac q p\right)^2\\
\left(pc-q\right)\left(pd-q\right)&=q^2=\lambda_1\cdot \lambda_2\\
c=\frac{q+\lambda_1}{p},\quad d&=\frac{q+\lambda_2}{p}
\end{aligned}$$
Whichever of these $c,d$ that wind up being integers is a solution.

Your question in and of itself may baffle those who are used to people coming on here and posting their homework problems.  But I see the value and the interest latent in this question.  How large can your expression go I wonder?  Can it be larger than $3263498$?